# How to create a login system in C

Tags: c

My assignment required me to create a simple login system by comparing the name and password of the customer in the file. When I'm only comparing the name it works, however, when I add another "%s" and s.pass in the line `while (fscanf(login,"%s %s",s.fname,s.pass) == 1)`, the name could not be compared as well as password. I would like to know is there another way to compare the input with a text file and print out the file data as well. Also, is there a way to compare the input with the first string and only the last string of the file?

Here is my full code for this system:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 


struct CustomerDetails  // Structure declaration
{
char fname[100];
char pass[100];
}s;


void main()
{
   FILE* login;
   login = fopen("login.txt", "r");
   char fname[100],pass[100];
   int valid = 0;

   // validate whether file can be opened.
   if (login == NULL)
   {
      printf("Could not create file");
      exit(0);
   }

   printf("Please enter your Full Name and Password to search your booking detail.\n");
   printf("\nFull Name: ");
   fgets(fname, 100, stdin);
   printf("Password: ");
   fgets(pass, 100, stdin);
   while (fscanf(login,"%s %s",s.fname,s.pass) == 1)
   {
       if (strcmp(fname,s.fname) == 0 && strcmp(pass, s.pass) == 0)
       {
           valid == 0;
           printf("\nRecord Found!");
           printf("\nFull Name: %s\n", s.fname); // to check whther the data in the file can be print
           printf("\nPassword: %s\n", s.pass);  // ^
           break;
       }
   }
   if (valid == 1)
   {
       printf("\nRecord not found!\n");
   }
   fclose(login);
}
```

Comment: The fscanf function returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned.

Comment: @user3121023 I've changed it and it still doesn't work

Comment: What's thje purpose of `valid == 0;`? Did you read the compiler warnings?

Comment: You're going to have to do some basic debugging here. Is the return value from fscanf correct (2)? Are all of fname, pass, s.fname and s.pass populated with correct values? Also, you seem to have inverted `valid` (it should be non-zero if the login is valid, zero if the login is not valid).

Comment: And are you aware that the line read via `fgets` has a trailing \n?

Comment: Can you add the login.txt file? It will help understanding the issue because aside from the ones mentioned above , there does not seem  to be any error in the code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I want to use valid = 1 to print out the "Record not found!" and there are no compiler warnings.

Comment: If you want `valid = 0` don't write `valid == 0`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for the reminder, I've added the code to remove trailing newline added by fgets

Comment: @user3121023 thanks for the reminder, I've added it but the login system is still not working

Comment: @DaoistPaul the file can be added, as I mentioned, the name can be compared but when I try to compare both of the name and password, the code is not working anymore

Comment: @user3121023 I think the while loop is skipped as it doesn't go through anything in the while

Comment: If I remove one of the %s and s.pass, it will go through the while loop and when I print s.name, it will print out all the data in the text file.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of your program is more or less correct.

But here are several bugs:

- you don't remove the trailing \n after fgets, therefore `strcmp` will always return 0
- you compare the result of `fscanf` to 1, instead of 2, `fscanf` returns the number of items successfully read, which should be 2 in this case (username and password).
- you use `valid == 0` which has no effect, and which is wrong anyway because you want `valid = 1;`. (`=` is not `==`)
- finally you print `Record not found!` if `valid` is 0 instead of 1

---

```
  ...
  fgets(fname, 100, stdin);
  fname[strcspn(fname, "\n")] = 0;   // get rid of the \n at the end of the line
  
  printf("Password: ");
  fgets(pass, 100, stdin);
  pass[strcspn(pass, "\n")] = 0;     // get rid of the \n at the end of the line

  while (fscanf(login, "%s %s", s.fname, s.pass) == 2)   // compare to 2, not to 1
  {
    if (strcmp(fname, s.fname) == 0 && strcmp(pass, s.pass) == 0)
    {
      valid = 1;                     // set valid to 1, not to 0 and use = not ==
      printf("\nRecord Found!");
      printf("\nFull Name: %s\n", s.fname);
      printf("\nPassword: %s\n", s.pass);
      break;
    }
  }

  if (valid == 0)      // compare to 0, not to 1
  {
    printf("\nRecord not found!\n");
  }
  ...
```

This works with following login.txt file:

```
user1 password1
user2 password2
```

The code above might not work with *your* login.txt file, for example if user names and password contain spaces.

Hint: learn how to use your debugger. With a debugger you would have found these problems in 10 minutes.

Comment: thank you! I will learn the debugger as soon as possible :)

Answer (score -1):

A proper login system should do the following:

Read directly from a tty not stdin. stdin is inherited by the parent process, so it may be redirected from somewhere. You want input directly from the keyboard.

If you choose to limit the password length and buffer sizes, make sure you have overflow checks on everything.

Store the passwords in locked down memory so that they don't get swapped to disk where an attacker could forensically retrieve the password.

When you store the passwords, make sure you salt and hash them using a modern cryptographically secure algorithm. Use a unique salt for each password.

Restrict the capabilities and permissions of the login process and password store to adhere to the principal of least privilege.

Comment: Considering the OP is a beginner, I think this is beyond his scope

Comment: It also doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: It's a broad question and the answer is appropriate, especially for posterity. It serves as an information source for anyone to enlighten themselves on the topic.

Comment: yes, while it might not answer op, it will surely help future readers.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to dv this. All what you write in the answer is correct, but it is almost totally unrelated to the question. The question title is misleading, the OP doesn't want to know how to create a login system, but he wants to know why his code he wrote as an exercise doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's fair and I understand where you're coming from, Jabs -- no hard feelings.